# How to manually edit a grid.arrange, ggplot_gtable and facet?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I'm ploting a [Hydrograph](https://rpubs.com/cxiao/hydrograph-ggplot2-plot) but I additionally use `facet_grid` in `R` because I have objects with common features.
But when I use `facet_grid` the plot gets distorted, as shown in the figure below. How can I randerize this?

[image]

Note that it is not aligned properly, the scale of the y axis is scrambled, etc.
Among the adjustments I tried, I realized that it is possible to greatly improve this plot. I've created an image based on the above plot, some other attempts on how I'm trying and making some adjustments to paint to demonstrate what I'm trying to do.

[image]

Here's my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

g1 <- ggplot(data_cet, 
         aes(x = Periodo,
             y = Ind_plu)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', 
           fill = "blue",
       position = position_dodge()) +
  ylab("Precip.") +
  scale_y_reverse(labels = scales::comma) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x  = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank())

g2 <- ggplot(data_cet, 
         aes(x      = Periodo,
             y      = Nivel,
             colour = Bomba)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = 1)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#0B775E", "#35274A", "#F2300F")) +
  labs(colour = "Status CMB") +
  facet_grid(data_cet$arranjo + data_cet$Bacia ~.) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = datebreaks_m, 
               labels = date_format("%b/%y")) +
  xlab('Período') + ylab('% Nível') +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x  = element_text(face  = "plain", 
                                    color = "black", 
                                    angle = 90),
    axis.text.y      = element_text(face  = "plain", 
                                    color = "black"),
    legend.title     = element_blank(),
    strip.background = element_blank(),
    legend.position  = "bottom")

g1 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(g1))
g2 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(g2))
maxWidth = unit.pmax(g1$widths[2:3], g2$widths[2:3])

g1$widths[2:3] <- maxWidth
g2$widths[2:3] <- maxWidth

plot_hyd <- grid.arrange(g1, g2, ncol = 1, heights = c(1, 3))
ggsave(file = "plot_hyd4.pdf", plot_hyd)
```

My dataset is too large, my apologize for not showing the dataset and `dput()`.

Comment: Something like this: `grid.arrange(g1, g2, ncol = 1, heights = c(1, 3), widths = c(0.9, 1))` ? The save in pdf format is because it was the only one that I can save faster without presenting a bug, but something like this do you think will work well? `ggsave(file="plot_hyd4.pdf",plot_hyd,width=13,height=21,dpi=600)`. I'm sorry for the kind of question, but it's because the plot is taking so long, it's a lot of data.

Comment: Yep!  I've deleted my comment and addressed your more recent comment in an answer format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the logic of the @Pintintended tip for the code. I adopted the [`layout_matrix`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/arrangeGrob.html#complex-layouts) argument.

```
>
plot_hyd <- grid.arrange(g1, g2, 
                     layout_matrix = rbind(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,NA),
                                           c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
                                           c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
                                           c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
                                           c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
                                           c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
                                           c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)))

#ggsave(file="plot_hyd4.jpeg",plot_hyd,width=13,height=16,dpi=200)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `widths = c(0.9, 1)` to `grid.arrange` (fiddle with the first number some) to get your graphs to line up along the right side.

Otherwise, `ggsave` your file to a larger pdf. Your element_text objects, such as the legend, are absolute sizes, so if you scale up the pdf dimensions your graphs will look larger by comparison.

The exact values of `widths` and `ggsave(width, height)` are going to depend on you data, and unfortunately will take some trial and error.  If you're using something like RStudio, I suggest fiddling with the `grid.arrange` call and finding the `widths` argument you like before calling `ggsave`.  When you are ready to experiment with different `ggsave` `width` and `height` arguments, run it at a lower `dpi` the first few times so it processes more quickly.

Note that since you haven't included your data, I haven't tried to recreate this problem - this is just how I've solved this kind of issue in the past.  If these suggestions don't work for you, let me know and I can use some built-in datasets to find another solution

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but for every change I make in width this error appears:`> plot_hyd <- grid.arrange (g1, g2,
+ ncol = 1,
+ heights = c (0.3, 3),
+ width = c (0.9, 1))
Error in arrangeGrob (...): nrow * ncol> = n is not TRUE`

Comment: If you're putting a `+` before `ncol`, `heights` and `widths`, take those out.  Also make sure `widths` is plural or it'll throw an `unknown argument`

Comment: I solved using layout_matrix, I'm done now! The `+` is from the R console, and the plural was a typo, sorry. I'll post the code response.

Comment: Thanks for the tips on how to proceed with `grid.arrange ()` !!